# Mysql Time Arithmetic - Time only

Tags: mysql

This should be so easy... but is driving me mad.

```
UPDATE time SET time = (time - interval 130 minute) WHERE stuff=whatever;
```

Time is a time column only, i.e. 09:00:00.

Comment: What's the question?  What happens?  What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you would like to subtract 130 minutes from the current time, you can use [`addtime`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime), like this:

```
UPDATE time SET time = addtime(time, '-02:10') where stuff=whatever
```

130 minutes is 2 hours and 10 minutes, hence the `-02:10` constant.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6614a/1) is a quick demo on sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Change **-** to **,** and it will work. The correct Query is:

```
UPDATE time SET time = (time, interval 130 minute) where stuff=whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

If time is a datetime or a timestmap, you must use a date_sub funktion

```
SELECT date_sub(time, interval 130 minute) FROM ....
```

Otherwise you can also convert your time with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, sub it and convert with `FROM_TIMESTAMP` into a mysql timestamp back

Answer (score 0):

There is a DATE_SUB method that works like the DATE_ADD method you are looking for.

DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 130 MINUTE)

Check this link for more information:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub